# What is the best way of keeping database in sync with the Redux store (redux middleware)?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I have a goal to keep my MongoDB database in sync with the current state of my application. For example, whenever my state changes (like the name of a project, for example), that change will be saved into the database after the action is dispatched and reducer is signaled and the state is changed.

As an example, I have a state object with the following structure:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
name: "",
triggered: false,
isUnique: false
};
```

So when a user changes the name of the project, that name change will be first be done by the state itself and after the state changes, there is a call to the DB to just change the name of the project.

To simulate a DB change, I used localStorage to get across the same purpose:

```
function handshake() {
    return ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {

        // send action to next Middleware
        next(action);

        const db = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("temporaryDB"));
        const presentState = getCurrentState(getState());

        if(db) {
            const areStatesEqual = isEqual(db, presentState);
            if(!areStatesEqual) return localStorage.setItem("temporaryDB", JSON.stringify(presentState));

            return;
        }

        localStorage.setItem("temporaryDB", JSON.stringify(presentState));
    };
  }

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        applyMiddleware(handshake())
    )
}
```

getCurrentState is just a utility function that gets the current state. Regardless, my logic is to use a Redux middleware and look for changes between the database object and the store object. If the objects are different in any way, I would replace the DB object with the Redux store, keeping everything in sync.

It's a naive approach and I'm looking to see if there is a better way of reaching the goal I have of keeping the state and database in sync throughout the entire application's lifecylce.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to subscribe to the store and listen to all the changes happening there.

e.g. two function to load/save state to keep it sync

```
export const loadState = () => {/*the DB logic*/}
export const saveState= () => {/*the DB logic*/}
```

then you can compose your redux with these function and initial the state with calling the loadState()

```
import { loadState, saveState } from "where theyare"
const syncWithDBstate= loadState();

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  syncWithDBstate,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)) // here I am suing the chrome devtool extention
);

store.subscribe(() => {
saveState(store.getState());
});
```